# Is there a "onsuccess" method for detect user's position on google maps api?

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm trying to call a function when I've detected user's position, but the only way that I've got to ensure it was using setTimeout() function. How can I get it without it?

```
_detectUserLocation: function(map, marker) {
  self = this;
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      map.setCenter(pos);
      map.setZoom(12);
      marker.setPosition(pos);

      self._updateAddressPartsViaReverseGeocode(marker.getPosition());
      setTimeout(function() {
        self._loadByUserLocation(self.parsed);
      }, 2000);
    }, function(error) {
      marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(-23.5489433, -46.6388182));
    }, { timeout:5000 });
  } 
  else {
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(-23.5489433, -46.6388182));
  }
},
```

For now, I have to use setTimeout() function to avoid JS call _loadByUserLocation() before the system got user's position.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What does the manual say about it?

Comment: No, just a comment. It will probably be in the manual, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

GetCurrentPosition has 3 options to set by default (success, error, options), as stated in the comments already. Take a look to the example and the end of the MDN site.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

You dont access a google api to detect your users position, thats a browser api.

Comment: I believe the way I did it is similar to tutorial. However, I don't not